# SQL to select all rows with duplicate values in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, duplicates

I have a `users` table that has duplicate values in the `employee_id` column. I need to list all rows with duplicate employee_ids, along with their names. I need to see all users with a duplicate `employee_id` so I can de-conflict which values are valid.

```
SELECT name,employee_id  
FROM users;

name     | employee_id
-----------------------
jason      12345
tom        34567 
jane       12345
will       01020
bill       12345
```

I need to return:

```
name       | employee_id
-------------------------
jason        12345
jane         12345
bill         12345
```

I see similar questions, but I still can't get the correct syntax I need. With the below I am only getting one occurrence. I need all occurances with duplicate `employee_id` like above.

```
SELECT employee_id, MAX(name) 
FROM users 
GROUP BY employee_id 
HAVING COUNT(employee_id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could use windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT sub.name, sub.employee_id
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY employee_id) AS c
      FROM users) AS sub
WHERE c > 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/FIEX19667)**</kbd>

or simple `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id 
                      FROM users 
                      GROUP BY employee_id 
                      HAVING COUNT(employee_id) > 1);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/DWOGA76796)**</kbd>

or correlated subquery:

```
SELECT name, employee_id
FROM users u
,LATERAL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u2 WHERE u.employee_id = u2.employee_id) AS s(c)
WHERE c > 1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d77d7/1/0)**</kbd>