# Get Different Distinct Pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing a site id, site name, and site address. I am trying to write up a query that will give me all instances of the same site name having a different site id and am having a difficult time..

```
site_id      site_name      site_address
  1        North Office       123 Test Rd.
  2           Eastern         456 Fake St.
  3        North Office       789 Data Ln.
  4        West Office        111 Western Ave.
  5        North Office       901 Delta Rd.
```

In my scenario I would be looking for a query that returns site ids 1, 3, and 5 because the ids are different but the site name is the same.

I haven't gotten very far in what I have tried because I am a bit lost. I have tried incoroporating a COUNT with the HAVING and GROUP BY but I keep getting errors..

```sql
SELECT site_id, site_name, site_address FROM table WHERE site_id IN (SELECT site_id FROM table WHERE...)
```

Comment: This is for PostgreSQL, but the solution for SQL Server is identical in this case: [SQL to select all rows with duplicate values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384107/sql-to-select-all-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-column)

Comment: @Larnu I have modified the examples in that question and they all seem to just be returning every single instance in the table, not exactly what I am looking for

Comment: I would suggest you've not implemented the solution properly then.

Comment: `select site_id, site_name, site_address
from 
(select *, min(site_address) over(partition by site_name) as minsite_address,
  max(site_address) over(partition by site_name) as maxsite_address 
from tableX) as t
where minsite_address <> maxsite_address`

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, probably failing on the group by. Here is a example of how it can be done

```
SELECT site_id, site_name, site_address
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE site_name IN (SELECT site_name FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY site_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT site_id) > 1)
```

Comment: 'table.site_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @D.Fowler didnt test it , now is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a SQL Server duplicate, however, this is effectively the same answer as in many other RDBMS, and very similar the solution in something like [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group); use a CTE/derived table to get the `COUNT`, and then filter on that:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SiteId,
           SiteName,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SiteName) AS Sites
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT SiteId,
       SiteName
FROM CTE
WHERE Sites > 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ALIMBx4-)

Comment: Doing this returns the ID and Name for all 20,000 rows in my table. I am looking for just the distinct scenarios where the same name has more than 1 distinct id

Comment: Then all 20,000 of the rows have at least one other row with the same `SiteID`, @D.Fowler .

Comment: For the sample data you've given, I only get the rows where `SiteId` has a value of `1`, `3`, and `5`. See the Fiddle I've added to the answer, @D.Fowler .